# Place dots above carousel in slickR?

Tags: r, slickr

In the package `slickR`, there is the option to show dots using the `settings`-function but how can I place those dots above the carousel instead of below?

From what I understand, one needs to write some CSS code but how and where?

```
my_plots <- (Plot1.png, Plot2.png, Plot3.png)

slickR::slickR(my_plots) +
  slickR::settings(slidesToShow = 1, dots = TRUE)
```